# ASP.NET page load soap calls

Tags: asp.net, soap, scalability

I'm making changes to a number of ASP.NET applications on a dedicated server and am wondering about the potential issues that might occur as a result of this.
Basically for every page load I will need to make at least one call  to a SOAP service on another server to obtain user data process it and render the page.

I may have to make one or two calls to the remote server in the Page_Load event depending on the situation.

The site handles large amounts of traffic on a daily basis and I'm wondering if there are limits on the amount of outbound connections the site cam make from within ASP.NET.
i.e. is it advisable to make as many outbound connections as inbound and how scalable dose this solution sound to be?

Thanks,
C